# create read methods for instance variables that use static hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, instance-variables

I have a class that has instance variables made of hashes.

require 'hashie'

```
class CardBrandFees < Hashie::Trash
  property :assessments, from: :assessmentss
  attr_reader :discover, :visa, :mastercard, :mc_high_ticket, :assessments, :APF

  def initialize(ticket)
    @ticket          = @ticket
    @discover        = {:assessments => 0.00105, :APF => 0.0195}
    @visa            = {:assessments => 0.00110, :APF => 0.0195}
    @mastercard      = {:assessments => 0.00110, :APF => 0.0195}
    @mc_high_ticket  = {:assessments => 0.00010}
  end
end
```

I would like to make a card brand object and be able to access these hashes via dot notation so:

```
cardbrand = CardBrandFees.new(ticket)
cardbrand.discover.assessments => 0.00105
```

I am having considerable difficulty accomplishing this, and not sure its even the most effective way to set this simple class up, I have tried hashie, but cant get that working, does anyone have a simple solution for this situation?

Comment: [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) can do this for you. You could also do it with a simple class that provides `assessments` and `APF` `attr_reader`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'ostruct'

class CardBrandFees
  attr_reader :discover, :visa, :mastercard, :mc_high_ticket, :assessments, :APF

  def initialize(ticket)
    @ticket         = ticket
    @discover       = OpenStruct.new(:assessments => 0.00105, :APF => 0.0195)
    @visa           = OpenStruct.new(:assessments => 0.00110, :APF => 0.0195)
    @mastercard     = OpenStruct.new(:assessments => 0.00110, :APF => 0.0195)
    @mc_high_ticket = OpenStruct.new(:assessments => 0.00010)
  end
end


p CardBrandFees.new("ticket").discover.assessments # => 0.00105
p CardBrandFees.new("ticket").mastercard.APF # => 0.0195
```